# Why is my probability negative?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The joint probability function of a pair of continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ are:
$f(x,y) = {(1\div8)(6-x-y), for \ 0<x<2, 2<y<4; 0 \ elsewhere}$

The question is to find the conditional density of $X$ given $Y=y$ and evaluate $P(X\geq1.5|Y = 3.5)$

$f(x|y) = f(x,y) \div h(y) = [(1\div8)(6-x-y)]\div[(3-y)\div4]$

plug $Y = y = 3.5 → (2x-5)\div2$

$P(X\leq 1.5|Y = 3.5) = integral \ (0 →1.5) [(2x-5)\div2]$

$dx = -21/8$

How is this possible? Could anyone help me out here, please?

Comment: Please use MathJax. This is too hard to read

Comment: I edited it now, but may have misconverted it

Comment: @C-RAM Did you post it twice by accident?

Comment: @EthanChan Yes. No idea how, since I posted it from review, where clicking once closes the prompt.

Comment: @EthanChan I think I did, I am sorry. Thank you for helping me to edit my post. My first time posting math formulas, I still don't know how to use Mathjax yet.

Comment: No problem. Here is an article on how to use it. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-baatorial-and-quick-reference.

This may make your computer lag a little

Comment: I'm finding this a bit hard to follow, but I think your $h(y)$ is wrong. I think it's $\frac{(5-y)}{4}$, not $\frac{(3-y)}{4}$

Comment: @CarlChaanin, I see, I used the wrong formula to calculate h(y). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error located:

$\qquad\begin{align}h(y) &=\int_0^2 (1/8)(6-x-y)\,\mathbf 1_{2\leq y\leq 4}\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex] &= (1/4)(~\color{red}5~-y)~\mathbf 1_{2\leq y\leq 4}\end{align}$

---

You can simplify thing so that calculation errors don't cascade.  For any $\langle a,b\rangle$ inside the support:

$$\mathsf P(X\leq a\mid Y=b)=\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_0^a f(x,b)\,\mathrm d x}{\displaystyle\int_0^2 f(x,b)\,\mathrm d x}$$
So
$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\leq 1.5\mid Y=3.5)&=\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_0^{1.5} (1/8)(6-x-3.5)\,\mathrm d x}{\displaystyle\int_0^2 (1/8)(6-x-3.5)\,\mathrm d x}\\ &=\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_0^{1.5} (2.5-x)\,\mathrm d x}{\displaystyle\int_0^2 (2.5-x)\,\mathrm d x}\end{align}$$

Then since $\displaystyle\int (2.5-x)\,\mathrm d x=2.5x-x^2/2$ ....

Comment: I commented that, but also I don't think the mistakes stop here. Not sure tho.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thank you so much for your help. I realised that I used the wrong formula to calculate my h(y).

Comment: @Ulffer Feel free to accept the answer. It would show that you appreciate the effort of Graham.